# Problem with 2-dimensional list in Python

Tags: python

Yesterday, I decided to start playing with Python for the first time, so please go easy on me, I have little to no programming experience.
As my first little project, I am trying to make a script that shuffles a deck of cards and deals 5-card hands from the shuffled deck.
I am trying to store the hands in a 2-dimensional array / matrix.
This is the code I am having trouble with:

```py
import random
sorted_deck =  ["AH","KH","QH","JH","TH","9H","8H","7H","6H","5H","4H","3H","2H",
                "AS","KS","QS","JS","TS","9S","8S","7S","6S","5S","4S","3S","2S",
                "AD","KD","QD","JD","TD","9D","8D","7D","6D","5D","4D","3D","2D",
                "AC","KC","QC","JC","TC","9C","8C","7C","6C","5C","4C","3C","2C"]

def shuffle():
    sorted_deck_current = list()
    sorted_deck_current.clear()
    sorted_deck_current = sorted_deck.copy()
    shuffled_deck = list()
    shuffled_deck.clear()
    for n in range(0,52):
        r = random.randrange( 0, len(sorted_deck_current) )
        shuffled_deck.append( sorted_deck_current[r] )
        sorted_deck_current.pop( r )
    return shuffled_deck

for n in range(2): # Check that the shuffle()-function works
    fresh_shuffled = shuffle()
    print( "Shuffled deck: " + str(fresh_shuffled) )

many_hands = list()
temp_hand = list()
temp_deck = list()
many_hands.clear()

for n in range(5): # Draw 5 hands from freshly shuffled decks
    temp_hand.clear()
    temp_deck.clear()
    temp_deck = shuffle()
    for i in range(5):
        temp_hand.append( temp_deck[i] )
    many_hands.append( temp_hand )
    print( many_hands[n] )

for q in range(5): # Try and output the 5 different hands again
    print( many_hands[q] )

exit()
```

My `for n in range(5)` loop towards the end of the code outputs 5 different hands, which is what I want.
The `for q in range(5)` loop outputs the same hand 5 times, which happens to be the last hand of the previous loop.
I can not figure out why this happens.
If anyone could explain this behaviour to me, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you print the first element of `many_hands` you notice it changes for each iteration. All hands are the same object.

Comment: `many_hands.append( temp_hand )` what this does is it appends to `many_hands` a *reference* to `temp_hand`. That means that `many_hands[0]` now points to the exact same list as `temp_hand`. So when you change `temp_hand` and then later call `many_hands[0]`, you're now pointing at the changed `temp_hand`. You're doing this 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the fix, make a new list object at each iteration:

```
for draw in range(5): # try avoid single letter variables
    temp_hand = [] # Make a NEW list object. BTW, [] is nicer and more common syntax than list()
    temp_deck = shuffle()
    temp_hand = temp_deck[:5] # Use slicing to get the first 5 elements, not a loop!
    many_hands.append(temp_hand) # This will get a different list object appended each time which is what you want.
```

So what went wrong? In python, when you assign a list to a variable, you don't assign a copy of the list but rather a reference to it. Try this code:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3] # Make a new list object
list2 = list1 # Assigns a reference to the existing list1
list1[0] = 9
print(list2)
```

you will see that `list2` has changed. This is because `list1` and `list2` point to the same object. You can check this in python using `is` or `id`:

```
print(f"list1 id: {id(list1)}")
print(f"list2 id: {id(list2)}")
```

They're the same. Also `list1 is list2` returns `True`.

But now try this:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

now `list1 == list2` is `True` but `list1 is list2` is `False`. They are separate objects.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
list1[0] = 9
print(list2)
```

This time `list2` hasn't changed.

In your original code you were keeping the reference to `temp_hand` alive by calling `.append()` instead of creating a new list object in each iteration. So in each loop you shuffle `temp_hand` and printed it and saw the new hand. But what you weren't looking at is what happened to the values already in `many_hands`. These were all point to the same object so they were *all* changing each iteration.

Here is another way to prove this:

```
list1 = []
for _ in range(5):
    list1.clear()
    list1.append(1) # It is really your use of append that is the culprit as this is where you EDIT an existing list instead of ASSIGNING a new one
    list2 = [1]
    print(f"list1 id: {id(list1)}, list2 id: {id(list2)}")
```

See how `list1` is always the same but `list2` changes each time?

---

btw my code in the beginning can be even shorter but I want to illustrate creating a list using `[]` but really `shuffle` makes a new list itself so you could have done this:

```
for draw in range(5): # try avoid single letter variables
    temp_hand = shuffle()[:5] 
    many_hands.append(temp_hand)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating `temp_hand` before you start the first `for` loop. Thereafter, you always end up modifying the same object, and then re-adding it to `many_hands`. In essence, you just added the same object five times. If you're familiar with C, it's like pass-by-reference: python doesn't copy the value of the list before appending it, it just appends a reference to the list.

So then later, when you try to print `many_hands`, it prints the same object 5 times.

The solution to this is to initialize `temp_hand` *inside* the `for` loop, rather than outside, so that it gets re-initialized (to a new reference) every iteration. That is, replace the line

```
temp_hand.clear()
```

which modifies the single list that you currently have, without changing its reference, with

```
temp_hand = list()
```

which creates a new empty list at a new reference and assigns it to `temp_hand`.

---

As an aside, it's usually preferred to use list literals (that is, `[]`) instead of the `list()` constructor when you're initializing an empty list. This is mostly because it stands out from code around it as being *definitely a list*, rather than a function call that happens to return one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new list for each hand, you empty & fill `temp_hand` for each hand, so that `many_hands` is a list of 5 references to that same list/hand.

If instead of `temp_hand.clear()` you do `temp_hand = list()` (making it a new, empty list), you should get what you expect.

Comment: Well, *not* copies. It's the *same* list object each time.