# Creating a zero matrix for matrix multiplication not working despite when creating the matrix via a loop

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to create a code that does matrix multiplication without numpy or zip*. The code works fine when I define the zero matrix that receives the result of the multiplication, but the results overlap when I try to make the variable get defined by a loop.

I obviously can't just define the empty matrix because the compiler gives an index out of range error, and the multiplication resultant matrix changes depending on input. I provided a screenshot to the empty matrix when it is defined and when letting the code create the empty matrix.

```py
def empty(X, Y):
  P=[]
  row=[]
  for r in range(len(Y[0])):
    row.append(0)
  for t in range(len(X)):
    P.append(row)
  return P

def multiply(X, Y):
  P=empty(X, Y)
  #P=[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
  for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(Y[0])):
      for k in range(len(Y)):
        P[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]
  return P

def One(X, Y):
  x=[]
  b=[]
  count=0
  for i in range(len(X)):
    b.append(1)
  x.append(b)
  x.append(X)
  return x

d=[[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
b=[[2, 4], [5, 6]]

print(multiply(d,b))
print(empty(d,b))
```

[image: https://imgur.com/3EVpyaF]

The two matrices look the same in the output window. The first one is the one I manually defined as `P=[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]`.
The second one is the one created from the `empty()` function. The result is different from the multiplication function; it is overwritten for some reason.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEV_en&ei=o1AnXc-iBY6flwSI0a7YCw&q=%22python+program+matrix+multiplication%22&oq=%22python+program+matrix+multiplication%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30j0i8i30l7.1802.3065..44264...0.0..0.120.196.1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30._AF6WqPBRFo

Comment: You're making the same mistake as in this seemingly different quetion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56990015/problem-with-2-dimensional-list-in-python/56990447#56990447 basically, all your rows in `P` reference the same list object `row`. So when you change `P[i][j]` you are effectively changing `P[:][j]`. You can make a copy of `row` like this: `P.append(row[:])`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I fixed the empty matrix function. It is working fine now.

Comment: @Nasser but the mistake you made is quite an important one to understand. I suggest you go through the answer in that link.

Comment: I think that you shouldn't use a variable called `X` and other called `x` in this case since this can lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: I did. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. I used nested list comprehension to create the zero matrix. I think just adding the zero list as rows didn't work previously and messed up the dimensions or list type.

The modified empty function:

```
def empty(X,Y):
 P=[]
 P= [[0 for i in range(len(Y[0]))] for j in range(len(X))]
 return P
```

Comment: Your original code was wrong because all the rows of your matrix were point to the same list. So if you changed one, you changed them all. Also `P=[]` is unnecessary as the list comprehension creates a new list anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Supplementary to [Nasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11770729/nasser)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56991749/creating-a-zero-matrix-for-matrix-multiplication-not-working-despite-when-creati/56992337#56992337):

You could implement your function like this, so that you don't need the variable `P`:

```py
def empty(X,Y):
    return [[0 for i in range(len(Y[0]))] for j in range(len(X))]
```